# Eclipse: hide jar files in Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have just moved to a new machine, and have reinstalled Eclipse (was Indigo, now Mars) and imported all my projects. However, the Package Explorer now shows every JAR file in the project at the top level of the project tree; the source folder is first, then dozens of JAR files, then the other project subdirectories (including the same JARs in the places where they're really located, but with funny new icons next to them). There is no longer a "filter" option in the View menu. How do I get rid of the JARs from the top-level view?

Comment: can you upload a screencap to here.

Comment: Your title says 'Project Explorer' but you then talk about 'Package Explorer' - which one is it?

Comment: The question is about how to use a certain program (Eclipse), not a programming quesion.

Comment: I meant Project Explorer...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Seems to be just an Eclipse funny. I opened Package Explorer just to see what was what and closed Project Explorer; then later I closed Package Explorer and reopened Project Explorer, and everything was normal again, all the JARs had gone away... bleugh.